# Trigger adrum-ext JS file outside of an onload event

Tags: appdynamics

I need to load `adrum-4.3.3.0.js` after the `onload` event. The problem with this is that `adrum-ext.js` is only injected into the page from `adrum.js` after the `onload` event of the page.

[See 3. in the docs for reference to the above](https://docs.appdynamics.com/21.3/en/end-user-monitoring/browser-monitoring/browser-real-user-monitoring/inject-the-javascript-agent#InjecttheJavaScriptAgent-EUEMvideoHowtheJavaScriptAgentWorks)

Is it possible to force `adrum-ext.js` to be injected into the page without the need for an `onload` event. I'd rather not manually force another `onload` event as it can interfere with other scripts running on the page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you have explained is not recommended as it will negatively impact the functionality of BRUM monitoring. The adrum.js script is intended to be loaded as early as possible on the page (ideally the first script to be loaded synchronously in the page).

This is required:

1. To be able to get accurate timings for loading of the page / resources
2. To capture page data such as Ajax events, resources, and errors from as early a point as possible
3. To make the ADRUM object available for use as soon as possible (to give capture / config options).